# Flagging relative frequency which is less than some threshold value as a Outlier in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy

I have a data-frame with character variables. My task is to calculate relative frequency for each variables and flag each values ( in corresponding new flag variable is binary) where relative frequency is less than some threshold value.

So far, I tried this ( It's working for one variable, I am not sure how this can be done in a loop or is there any better and more efficient Solution to my problem

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Name': ['Alice', 'Alice ', 'Barbara', 'Carol', 'Henry','ds','sed'],
        'Sex' : ['M','F','F','F','M','f','m'],
        'Age' : [14,13,13,14,12,13,14],
        'Weight': [69.0, 56.5, 65.3, 62.8, 65.3,67,69],
        'Height': [112.5, 84.0, 98.0, 102.5, 102.5,101,105.3]}

cl =  pd.DataFrame(data)

# this is just to test on char variables 
cl1=cl.drop(['Age','Height','Weight'],axis=1).copy()

x=(cl.Sex.value_counts()/cl.shape[0]*100).to_frame().reset_index()
x.columns = ['Sex', 'Freq']

pd.merge(cl, x, on='Sex', how ='left')
```

I also tried on my real dataset - but it's showing NaN (however, I now know the reason)

```
for i in range(len(cat_data.columns)):
    cat_data[str(cat_data.columns[i])+str('_flag')] =  (cat_data.iloc[:,i].value_counts()/cat_data.shape[0]*100).sort_values(ascending=False)
```

I need flag variables for each char variable in a output data-set , for example cl will have sex_flag and name_flag or age_flag(in i consider it a char variable)

desired output will be like:

cat_data is equivalent to cl1 in above code. desired output will be like :

[image]
later need to drop AGE_freq column

Comment: What is `cat_data`? Can you show is your desired output?

Comment: Can you put that into your question? It is unreadable in the comment.

Comment: cat_data is equivalent to cl1 in above code. desired output will be like :   I am unable to put the right format here but the desired output will have all columns, along with the corresponding flag variables ( age -- age_flag , sex --  sex_flag )

Comment: How are you flagging them? What are the threshold values?

Comment: in this example , its 14.28571 , if age_freq is eq 14.28571 then mark it as 1 else 0 . In real data I will flag them if relative freq is eq to 1 %

Comment: The calculations in the image seems wrong altogether! How can the frequency for same age 14, be different in all 3 occasions? :( I suggest you come up with a [MCVE] .

Comment: Just to correct it , the shown freq was for sex column , if you try to run the first code till pd.merge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the code to get frequency and then have a threshold of 25%.

```
freq = cl.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).round(2).to_dict()))
freq = pd.DataFrame(np.where(freq>25, 1, 0), columns=freq.columns)
freq.columns = [x+'_flag' for x in freq.columns]
pd.concat([cl, freq],1)
```

Output:

```
       Name Sex  Age  Weight  Height  Name_flag  Sex_flag  Age_flag  Weight_flag  Height_flag
0    Alice   M   14    69.0   112.5          0         1         1            1            0
1   Alice    F   13    56.5    84.0          0         1         1            0            0
2  Barbara   F   13    65.3    98.0          0         1         1            1            0
3    Carol   F   14    62.8   102.5          0         1         1            0            1
4    Henry   M   12    65.3   102.5          0         1         0            1            1
5       ds   f   13    67.0   101.0          0         0         1            0            0
6      sed   m   14    69.0   105.3          0         0         1            1            0
```

Comment: I don't want to keep freq columns, instead I need to create flag variable with 1/0 based on a set threshold value for each columns

Comment: Thanks for providing clean and efficient solution. I am always curious to know about lambda and map functionality

Comment: Can I subset my rows based on these flag variables where value is equal to 1?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Name': ['Alice', 'Alice ', 'Barbara', 'Carol', 'Henry','ds','sed'],
        'Sex' : ['M','F','F','F','M','f','m'],
        'Age' : [14,13,13,14,12,13,14],
        'Weight': [69.0, 56.5, 65.3, 62.8, 65.3,67,69],
        'Height': [112.5, 84.0, 98.0, 102.5, 102.5,101,105.3]}

cl =  pd.DataFrame(data)
req_df=cl.copy()

col1=cl.columns[0]
cols=cl.columns[1:]

for col in cols:
    temp_df=cl[[col1,col]]
    x=temp_df[temp_df.columns[-1]].value_counts()/cl.shape[0]
    x=x.to_frame().reset_index()
    x.columns = [col, 'Freq'+str(col)]
    req_df=pd.merge(req_df, x, on=col, how ='left')
```

[image: output:::]

Comment: You do not need to loop through for this simple operation.

Comment: `cl.apply(lambda x: x.map(x.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100).to_dict()))`

Comment: @harvpan I need to drop freq columns, Instead I need flag variable for each with 1/0 based on threshold values